# what is Baas (Backend as a service) .with examples

Tags: cloud, serverless

There are various cloud services available today, such as Amazon's EC2 and AWS, Apache Hadoop, Microsoft Azure, Amazon faragate, tensorflow, and many others. To which category does each belong and why?

Comment: You clearly haven't even tried to do any homework on this

Comment: I have tried but cant get an answer a developer needs

Comment: Pretty much none of what you listed would be BaaS. 
 Most of those things are cloud services. 
 You should read this: https://martinfowler.com/articles/serverless.html